# Python Multithreading - not running simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

im trying to learn python. But i have problems with the threading. First i failed in the "Proces" class because i putted the loop on the wrong place and my program newer returned from the other class.

But now i think all is correct and it still does not work. **I need to have a GUI where i want to be able to write my conditions via text entries and i need another class "Proces" that will do stuff, checking status ower internet and so on constantly or in a specified interval...**

***The Problem is that my tkinter GUI is freezing after pressing something***

*here is my GUI.py file:*

```
import tkinter as tk
from Proces import Proces


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red",command=quit).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

pr = Proces()
print("\nGUI: proces init...")
pr.start()
print("\nGUI: Start ended")

root.mainloop()
```

*here is the Proces.py file:*

```
import time, threading


class Proces(threading.Thread):
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            print("\nProces: looping")

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("\nProces: Starting proces")
        time.sleep(2)

    def run(self):
        self.deamon = True
        print("\nProces: Starting loop")
        self.loop()
```

*This is the output: *

```
Proces: Starting proces
GUI: proces init...
Proces: Starting loop
GUI: Start ended
Proces: looping
Proces: looping
Proces: looping
Proces: looping
```

*But the GUI of the *tkinter* does not react.*

**How should i do this kind of task?
Thank you for your help, advice and answer**

Comment: why do you have a 2 second sleep in your `Proces.__init__`? this sleep is on the main thread so stops the GUI from rendering until its over?

Comment: There is a typo in the `Proces` class, it should be `self.daemon = True`, not `self.deamon = True`.

Comment: @JamesKent the sleep is there just because i'm still just learning, just for testing to delay threads

Comment: @j_4321 The deamon typo error i did not notice. But I wondered why the other thread did not end with the first one. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have problem about starting thread etc. However, you should be able to control your thread, meaning your thread should return based on some condition. It seems you have a button to quit. I assume you want to finish the process by clicking the button.
 To do that, when you click to button, your main thread should pass a variable to Process in order to break your `while` loop, which is your thread basically.
 Here is a code that you can work on.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):

    self.master = master
    self.quit_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="QUIT", command=lambda:self.quit(), width=20)
    self.quit_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.process = None
    print("\nGUI: process init...")
    self.start_task()


    def quit(self):
      self.process.stop_process = True
      print("\nGUI: Start ended")

    def start_task(self):
      self.process = Process()
      self.process.start()


class Process(threading.Thread):
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            if not self.stop_process:
                time.sleep(2)
                print("\nProcess: looping")
            else:
                print("\nProcess: looping ended")
                return

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_process = False
        print("\nProcess: Starting proces")
        time.sleep(2)

    def run(self):
        self.deamon = True
        print("\nProcess: Starting loop")
        self.loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

So you start yout tkinter, which is your main thread. Then iniating another class within your main thread, which is inherits the thread. So you have two seperate thread that working. When you clicked to "quit" button, you pass variable `stop_process`, which breaks the loop and return, meaning ending your thread. Your main thread is still alive for running your tkinter window.

I hope it will help

Comment: Your code works, and yes it helped. But i don't understand why the **GUI window freezes in my program after clicking on it.**
In the code i wittingly removed the quit function so there's not a lot of code to focus on. But all it did was "print("klik")"

Comment: I meant clicking on the button not in the frame

Comment: @Tomas Hello, if you remove the quit button, your  2nd thread will run infinitely, unless you return "Process" in other way. The program that I wrote not supposed to freeze. For example, you can add a text widget into your window. Program will run the thread and in the meanwhile you can interact with your main window, for example typing in text field. Because, your main window and your process are running in different thread.